# How to include a cover letter when applying for jobs via Stack Overflow Developer Jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I just submitted my first application for a job on Stack Overflow Jobs, but I couldn't find where and how to attach a cover letter.

[image]

The only place to upload anything was the `CV / Resume` in the screenshot above. This led me to believe (at least hope) that clicking the `Apply Now` button would take me to a next step that would let me write or upload a cover letter.

But all I got was

[image]

Am I supposed to include the cover letter as part of the `CV / Resume` that I upload?

Comment: That doesn't look like our built-in application process (which does offer support for cover letters); it looks like an application process offered by the company itself. Companies can choose to use our built-in process or provide their own. I'm afraid we have little control over the latter :(

Comment: @DeanWard not related but was the developer job updated? I cannot find if the company wants a Junior/mid-level/Senior.

Comment: @PeterHaddad confused, which developer job?

Comment: @DeanWard any job, example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/170977/android-engineer-the-app-business (there used to be a place under the job title with the position level example: `"level: junior/mid-level/Senior"`)

Comment: @PeterHaddad looks like a regression, following up with the team

Comment: @PeterHaddad thanks for the heads up, an inverted condition got missed during a code review. Fix is going out to prod... Sadly, my fault :(

Comment: @DeanWard okay that's great! Also it's fine, it happens!

Comment: @DeanWard I see. A bit confusing though as the StackOverflow logo is displayed on the application website (here's the actual job application on [aplitrak.com](http://www.aplitrak.com/?adid=c3RlZmFuaWFjLjkxODIwLjY5ODFAYmlnd2VkbmVzZGF5LmFwbGl0cmFrLmNvbQ)).

Comment: @BadCash I've brought it up with our support folks, they should be able to reach out to the client and see if they can do something about it